# Rails 3 Console Sandbox Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to Rails, and I wanted to test some associations using the *rails console sandbox*.  I have a very basic app created, and the *rails console* works just fine.

I installed the activesupport gem.

When I run the `$ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]['adapter']` command, it reports back that the database is sqlite3 (which is correct.)

But when I try to use the "sandbox" version of the console I get the following error:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:45:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:39:in `resolve_string_connection'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:23:in `spec'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:721:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:41:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `call'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `block in load_console'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `each'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `load_console'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:429:in `block in load_console'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:429:in `load_console'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:153:in `load_console'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
```

I'm not really sure what this error is telling me, as I have the database.yml file set up correctly and data writes to the database using the standard console.  I also have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Can you paste your database.yml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass sandbox as a param

```
rails c --sandbox
```

otherwise rails think sandbox is the environment you want to run the console in.

Comment: Duh duh duh.  Thank you both!